# spec.volumes[1].name: Duplicate value: "workspace-volume"

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I'm using jenkins to start my builds in a kubernetes cluster via the kubernetes plugin.
When trying to set my jenkins `workspace-volume` to `medium: Memory` so that it runs in RAM, I receive the following error:

```
spec.volumes[1].name: Duplicate value: "workspace-volume"
```

This is the corresponding yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jenkins-job-xyz
  labels:
    identifier: jenkins-job-xyz
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: jnlp
    image: 'jenkins/jnlp-slave:alpine'
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workspace-volume
      mountPath: /home/jenkins
  - name: maven
    image: maven:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workspace-volume
      mountPath: /home/jenkins
  volumes:
    - name: workspace-volume
      emptyDir:
        medium: Memory
```

The only thing I added is the `volumes:` part at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volume `workspace-volume` is auto-generated by the kubernetes plugin and so a manual declaration will result in a duplicate entry.

For running the `workspace-volume` in RAM, set

```
workspaceVolume: emptyDirWorkspaceVolume(memory: true)
```

inside the `podTemplate` closure according to the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes/).